# How can I create a newsletter with the last five news nodes?

Tags: 8, emails

I need to create a newsletter where І can send the latest five news nodes in Drupal 8. Maybe you can recommend any module or custom method. I tried to use the Simplenews module, but with Drupal 8 nothing comes out.

Answer (score 1):

1/Create a view with the last new nodes (and their fields) with a block display

2/Make this view's display available as a variable for your newsletter by using a preprocess function in YOURTHEME.theme, something like:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_simplenews_newsletter_body(&$variables) {
$variables['latestnews'] = views_embed_view('latestnews', 'block_1');
}
```

Create a template for the newsletter body simplenews-newsletter-body--[newsletter_id].html.twig (newsletter_id = machine name).
and add your view in it where you'd like to:

```
{{ latestnews }}
```

Then, on top of it, you may need to use Swiftmailer/Mimemail for better styling output. That requires another layer of configuration and template.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [free Mailchimp plan](https://mailchimp.com/pricing/) and create a campaign that uses an RSS feed to populate its content. The RSS feed can be created by Views. In the View, set a filter to select only News content type, sorted by created DESC, that are published, and set a limit to 5 results only. Then just select the fields from the content type that you want to output in the View.

I have never had a lot of luck trying to run newsletters out of Drupal itself. You wouldn't need any module to do this other than Views.

Mailchimp has a lot of tokens and helpers to help you inject the RSS feed content and work with it. Its how we run our own internal newsletters.